# Disconnect event fire after 2 minutes

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using node.js and socket.io to create a chat application.

```
socket.on('disconnect',function(data){
    console.log("disconnected");
}
```

This event is fired as soon as the client gets disconnected(tab closed or network problem).

I want the disconnect event to be fired after 1 minute of disconnection from client. Is that possible? Is there any configuration in socket.io?

Comment: Why would this be useful? It's easy enough to add your own timeout for one minute *after* receiving a disconnect event.

Comment: If there is already an option in socket.io, I can use that instead of writing my own function for timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That capability is not built into socket.io.  The disconnect event fires when the socket is disconnected.  Period.  If you want to trigger some activity 1 minute after a disconnect, you can build your own timer to do so.

```
socket.on('disconnect',function(data){
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("disconnected");
    }, 60 * 1000);
}
```

If you want to trigger your event only if the client does not reconnect within 1 minute, then you can code that also, but it is a little more involved as you have to save the timer for the `setTimeout()` and then cancel it if that specific client reconnects before the timer fires.

---

Based on what you put in your answer, here's what I think is an improved version:

```
(function() {
    var origClose = socket.onclose;
    socket.onclose = function(reason){
      var self = this;
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

      /* Delay of 1 second to remove from all rooms and disconnect the id */
      setTimeout(function() {
          origClose.apply(self, args);
      }, 60 * 1000);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some parameters to control this behavior server-side. See `close timeout` and `heartbeat timeout` [here](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO)
and if you're using v1.0 you'll need to set the options in the new style described [here.](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#configuration-differences)

Note that these don't technically do what you're asking - they simply lengthen the amount of time a client has to reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

[Socket.onclose](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L416-L426) is fired immediately after disconnection before the disconnect event. 
disconnect event can be delayed by changing as follows.

```
socket.onclose = function(reason){
  console.log(socket.adapter.sids[socket.id]);
  Object.getPrototypeOf(this).onclose.call(this,reason);

  /* Delay of 1 seconds to remove from all rooms and disconnect the id */
  setTimeout(function() {
      if (!this.connected) return this;
      debug('closing socket - reason %s', reason);
      this.leaveAll();
      this.nsp.remove(this);
      this.client.remove(this);
      this.connected = false;
      this.disconnected = true;
      delete this.nsp.connected[this.id];
      this.emit('disconnect', reason);
  }, 60 * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Why do you call the regular `onclose()` before your `setTimeout()`?  Won't that just cause the disconnect event to fire immediately?  Doesn't that defeat the purpose of what you're doing?  Can't you just call the prototype.onclose in your timeout and not duplicate all the code you are duplicating which can easily break in the future if the implementation changes?  I see what you're getting at with this and it appears you can solve your problem in this direction, but the code you've posted doesn't look right.

Comment: See what I put at the end of my prior answer for what I think is an improved version.  FYI, yours will not work as you've shown it because `this` is not correct inside the `setTimeout()` callback.